# Azure API Apps, not returning model state errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, azure, azure-api-apps

I have a ASP.net Web API using the "Azure API app preview" template in Visual Studio 2015 that I am deploying to an Azure API App.

In my application I am using [model attribute validation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api), and a action filter as described in [this](http://sergeyakopov.com/2015/03/restful-validation-with-aspnet-web-api-and-fluentvalidation) article to call `ModelState.isValid` on all http requests coming in, and return the model state with errors in a http 400 response.

This all works perfectly locally, and indeed when deployed to an Azure Web Site, but when deploying the same code to an Azure API APP the request seems to be getting re-wrapped in a new response (see below, it appears to be adding status and source fields to the json) and the results of the model state errors dropped from the request.

Is there a way I can force API Apps to include these in the re-wrapped response, or indeed is this a bug? A 400 response without the underlying errors is not of much use to any API user. [I have seen others over on MSDN forums with the same issue.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1924bdd-31d4-45ab-a098-d539d3e86845/returning-modelstate-from-web-api-works-locally-but-not-when-hosted?forum=AzureAPIApps)

**Results locally & Result on Azure Web Site**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{
  "Message":"The request is invalid.",
  "Errors":
       {
         "InitialAmount":["The value 'a' is not valid for InitialAmount.",
                "The InitialAmount field is required."]
       }
}
```

**Results Azure Api Apps**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{
  "status": 400,
  "source": "https://MYAPIAPP.azurewebsites.net/api/Test?InitialAmount=a",
  "message": "The request is invalid."
}
```